# How to convert a lump set of PPM files to a single .mp4 video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert some `.ppm` files into a single video using ffmpeg. The images are listed as `image10.ppm`, `image20.ppm`, all the way up to `image2000.ppm`

Essentially, there are 200 images following the format of `image(1-200)0.ppm` in a single folder.

I've navigated to the correct folder containing the images using `cd` and the terminal displays this folder as the directory I'm in.

Inputting the following command into the terminal:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -f image2 -s 500x500 -i image%04d.ppm -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p presentation_video.mp4
```

I get the error that says:

```
[image2 @ 0x7ff36180ba00] Could find no file with path 'image%04d.ppm' and index in the range 0-4
image%04d.ppm: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing? I've just downloaded ffmpeg and am fairly new in general to command line interface.

Answer (score 3):

Your image inputs file names do not contain leading zeros, such as `image0002.ppm`, so use the the sequence pattern `image%d.ppm`:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i image%d.ppm -c:v libx264 -crf 25 -vf "scale=500:500,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

See the [image demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) for more details about the sequence pattern.